# Python: Type error: method receives more arguments than the ones given

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, typeerror

I have created this class to determine the normalisation function of a distribution.
Here is the class with relative main:

```
class Normaliser(object):

    def funcN(f, xIni, xFin, yIni, yFin): 

        return sym.integrate(f, (x, xIni, 
        xFin), (y, yIni, yFin))


def main():
    f = (1+sym.cos(x)**2)*sym.exp(-y/t)
    g = (3*sym.sin(x)**2)*sym.exp(-y/t)
    xIni = 0.
    xFin = 2*pi
    yIni = 0.
    yFin = 10.
    tau1 = 1.
    tau2 = 2.
    *funcN1 = Normaliser().funcN(f, xIni,             
    xFin, yIni, yFin)*  
    *funcN2 = Normaliser().funcN(g, xIni, 
    xFin, yIni, yFin)*
```

When I run the tester I get the following error in the *emphasised* lines:

```
TypeError: funcN() takes exactly 5 
arguments (6 given)
```

I really don't understand where this error is arising from considering that there is no self in the method. If anybody has any idea of a possible reason and possibly for a solution as well, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  regular member function of the `Normaliser` class, `funcN` is passed the `Normaliser` object it is being invoked on (canonically named `self`) as the first parameter.  This implicit parameter is added before any explicit parameters.
Since you defined the function to take five parameters and passed five explicit parameters, the function is called with six parameters - one implicit, and five explicit.
If `funcN` doesn't use any (instance or class) member variables of `Normaliser`, it could be defined outside any class or marked with the `@staticmethod` decorator to avoid the implicit `self` being added.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I understand it much better now! However another doubt arises now, do you think it is ok to make a class only with static methods or is it malpractice?

Comment: If they have something in common (e.g., they all work on the same data structure or are steps in a process) I don't see any problem, especially if there are only a few methods.  I think it's more conventional to use a module for this kind of grouping; invocation of a staticmethods and a module-level function is the same. The `time` module is an example of a module like this (although it is implemented in C, so it's not a perfect example).